# How do I send_keys a down arrow in capybara

Tags: html, ruby, selenium, cucumber, capybara

I have a special listbox that I could automate best by sending a down arrow and pressing enter.

I can press enter like so:

```
listbox_example = find(input, "listbox-example")
listbox-example.set("stuff")
#down arrow command goes here
listbox-example.native.send_keys :return
```

How do I write the down arrow command?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If I remember correctly the correct way to send the down arrow command is to use arrow_down

So your code should look like this

```
listbox-example.native.sendkeys :arrow_down
```

If you would like a list of all the available keys that you can send, then docs are your friend here

http://www.ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/f/frameworks-capybara-0.2.18/SendKeys.html

EDIT:  This link might have the intended content.
https://www.omniref.com/ruby/gems/frameworks-capybara/0.2.18/symbols/SendKeys

Comment: I don't why I missed it before, but that nailed it. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe it was different before, but today it's `send_keys`, not `sendkeys`

Answer (score 2):

```
find('#element_id').send_keys :arrow_down
```

Answer (score 1):

These answers are dependent on the driver I believe. I am using the Apparition js driver (i.e., it's a plugin for capybara) and the magic code that works is this:

```
find("input[type='search']").send_keys(:down).send_keys(:enter)
```

Using Capybara 3.33.0

Using the [Apparition JS driver (plugin for capybara)](https://github.com/twalpole/apparition) version 0.6.0

Answer (score 0):

If anyone lands here in 2023, it's sendkeys :down (not :arrow_down)

Answer (score -1):

These days (Capybara version 2.5+) you can simulate `<enter>` key in the following way:

```
find('.selector').set("text\n")
```

The `\n` is key here. I think you should be able to simulate down arrow in a very similar way.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the down-arrow part