# send_key gives segmentation fault in Rspec/Poltergeist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

In my spec for my Rails app, I am trying to use an approach similar to [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13916671/how-do-i-send-keys-a-down-arrow-in-capybara) to simulate the enter key being pressed. I have a form text field assigned to the variable `form`, and I try this:

```
form.native.send_key(:Enter)
```

This gives me a segfault:

```
/Users/<other path info>/spec/features/admin/users_spec.rb:78: [BUG] Segmentation fault ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-darwin13.3.0]
```

The interesting part is that if I use pry, then type this command on the pry prompt, it works fine, and the desired effect is achieved. Any help would be appreciated!

**Edit**

Here is the code from `users_spec.rb`:

```
    form = find("#term")
    form.set("foo")
    form.native.send_key(:Enter) # Line 78
    expect(current_path).to eq admin_user_path(user2)
```

Comment: It should be `:enter`, from the reference of available keys: https://github.com/rdeguzman/selenium-webdriver/blob/master/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/keys.rb. Can you also post the related code of users_spec.rb around line 78?

Comment: I don't think I'm using Selenium. The driver I'm using is Poltergeist. I got this spec to work by putting `sleep 5` on line 78, and leaving `:Enter` rather than changing to `:enter`. It seems that the JS must not have returned before the spec finished.